# How to add a powershell script/command as userdata for Windows VMs in Azure

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, virtual-machine, user-data

I am trying out the feature of `userdata` provided by Azure to pass scripts/metadata to VMs running on Azure.

For Linux VMs, I have tried passing a bash script, which involves creating a file. But I am trying the same for Windows VMs, but however the script doesn't get executed.

Through Azure's IMDS, I queried the userdata, and it returned the userdata that I passed when I created the VM.

So I am not really sure what's going wrong,whether I am passing the powershell commands in the wrong syntax etc.

This the command I passed as userdata to Azure Windows VM : `New-Item -Path C:\Users\Public\tstfile2.txt -ItemType File` , I am trying to create a temporary file in a directory and I am trying to verify whether the command passed as userdata get's executed or not but doing a `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Public\ -Name` and checking if the newly created file is present or not.

If someone has any idea/insights, please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the issue in my environment and got the below results***
*I have created new file and executed the below command using PowerShell.*

```
New-Item -Path C:\Users\Public\tstfile3.txt -ItemType File
```

***When I execute the command I got the newly created file in below***

[image]

***I have used the below command to check the file is available or not***

```
    Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Public\ -Name
```

[image]

***I have created the Windows VM***

[image]

***In the windows VM*** ,

- *Click on run command*
- *Click on RunPowerShell script*
- *Write the PowerShell script*
- *Click on Run*

[image]

***I got the newly created file in the below***

[image]

Comment: From the above, it looks like the commands were just run directly on the VM after it was provisioned. Did these commands also run automatically/successfully at VM creation time when they were added to the VMs userdata?

Comment: @blashmet were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing same issue, how did you resolve this?